# Transfer of js var to php file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have HTML5 table with each row consisting of name, address and reference number. Each row also has a button at the end that when the user clicks I need to capture the reference number as a javascript variable and send it to a php file to enable me to search my database using this unique reference.

The code fragments below show what happens when the button is clicked, the process() function that sends the data, and the function that creates the xmlHttp object.

The problem is that even though it captures the reference number variable successfully, it doesnt transfer it to the php file. I know the connection is ok as I have set up alerts at ready states 1,2,3,4 and 200 - all these are ok.

I know also that the variable in the php file is never set by testing it with isset().

Confused and wasting lots and lots of time :(

Thanks for looking.

```
  var referenceNumber;

  jQuery('.getrowdata').on('click', function() // called when button in html table is clicked
   {    
     var $row = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
     var $columns = $row.find('td');
     var value; 
     jQuery.each($columns, function(i, item)
      {
        value = item.innerHTML;
        if(i < 6)
         {
           selectedRowArray.push(value); // adds each element of the table to the array
         }
        referenceNumber = selectedRowArray[5]; // the unique ref that i need to query the dbase
      }
    );
     createXmlHttpRequestObject(); // function given below 
     process();                    // function given below
     window.open("myphpfile.php");  /* file that will use the newly set ref number to query the dbase and  display the query results */
   }); 


 function process()
   {
         xmlHttp.open("GET","myphpfile.php?phpref="+referenceNumber,true); /*transfer the js var to php var*/
         xmlHttp.send(null);
   }


 function createXmlHttpRequestObject() 
   {
     var xmlHttp;

     if(window.XMLHttpRequest) 
      {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();      
      }
     else
      {
         xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");// the user is using IE
      }
     return xmlHttp;
   }

 /*php code below as requested*/

  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "yes" ?>';

  $phpref;
  $phpref = $_GET['phpref'];

  if(isset($phpref))
   {
     echo $phpref;
   }
  else
  {
    echo "NOT SET!";
  }
```

Comment: opening the file in a new window is a separate request from the AJAX call. That window can't see variables on your page. You're also mixing jQuery with regular Javascript. jQuery has Javascript built in. Look at `.get()` or `.ajax()` methods to execute the PHP in the background then do something with the data.

Comment: Can you show your PHP code?

Comment: Did you check your javascript error console? From a quick look, it seems to me that in createXmlHttpRequestObject() you create the xmlHttp LOCAL variable, and then in process() you try to use it as if it was a global.
Besides, sending a value via AJAX, and then reopening the page with window.open WON'T automagically retain the value. They're two completely different and unrelated HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys but still confused. How do we get the php file to retain the values?